# What is the proper encoding for european special character?

Tags: python, encoding

I'm trying to treat EU law articles, and they have many special characters like ü, ä, ö, ß or è.
when I write a file without encoding this error message has occurred.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'cp949' codec can't encode character '\xf6' in position 22: illegal multibyte sequence
```

So I used `UTF-8` encoding, but the result was not the original characters, it was changed in improper characters like `C척te d'Ivoire`.
someone recommended to use `cp1250`, but another error message has occurred.

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xe8' in position 80: character maps to <undefined>
```

Can someone tell me what proper encoding is? I need to use original characters because I'll use these texts for classification labels.

Comment: 'iso 8859-15', also known as 'latin 9' ?

Comment: @ThierryLathuille It also made an error message `UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 58: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: I don't think there's a single 8-bit encoding that covers all the languages in the EU. In particular, U+2019 is  "RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK" which is extremely unlikely to exist in any 8-bit encoding. And I am not sure I understand what you are trying to do. Do you have text as strings in a Python program, which you are trying to output in a format that some other program can accept as input? In that case, you should probably check the documentation for that program for what encoding it accepts.

Comment: @TurePålsson thank you for your information, I'll just use utf-8 and find the other way of using it as an label.

Comment: `cp1250` is for _Central and Eastern Europe_; Try _Western Europe_ `cp1252`?